# why snapstore shows a name for a developer for a certain program, when the original download website shows anotherone?

Tags: security, snap, downloads, snap-store

I downloaded OBS using the snapstore and the developer is **Snapcrafters**. But the official website belongs to **OBSproject**. Why this happens and... is it safe?

Comment: You're not confusing the publisher of the *snap* with the upstream author of the program that is being snapped are you?  An example of what you're asking about (ie. link) may allow more precise answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is snapcrafters and what does it mean if it is listed as the developer of some apps on Ubuntu Software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070686/what-is-snapcrafters-and-what-does-it-mean-if-it-is-listed-as-the-developer-of-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The “Snapcrafters” are a group of community contributors working to get snaps published by upstream projects, with install instructions on the project homepage and the snapcraft.yaml in the project code repository.
>
> Snapcrafters is a `Github` area where developers can package their **snap** applications. You can find [**GIMP**](https://github.com/snapcrafters/gimp/blob/master/README.md) there too. Apparently, developers find publishing their apps as snap applications is easier than publishing them as `.deb` files installed with `sudo apt install ...`. Furthermore putting their snaps in Snapcrafters is even easier.

Source - [What is snapcrafters and what does it mean if it is listed as the developer of some apps on Ubuntu Software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1070686/1460940)

#### Conclusion

If you trust the actual developers of the package, then SnapCrafters is safe. In simple words, the actual developer of the package has published it using snap crafters, as it is easy to publish with snap crafters than publishing the whole deb file or publishing the whole snap software by there self.